# Javascript global string replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a comment textarea `#reply-textarea`:

```
var message = $('#reply-textarea').val();
var message = message.replace(/[img]/g,"<img src='");
var message = message.replace(/[\/img]/g,"'/>");
```

This allows an image, for example `[img]http://link-to-image.jpg[/img]` to be displayed as `<img src='http://link-to-image.jpg'/>` onto the page.

However it's producing something weird like:

`[<'/>'/>'/> src='<'/>'/>'/> src='<'/>'/>'/> src=']http:'/>'/>www.joo<'/>'/>'/> src='laworks.net'/><'/>'/>'/> src='<'/>'/>'/> src='a<'/>'/>'/> src='es'/>de<'/>'/>'/> src='os'/><'/>'/>'/> src='aller<'/>'/>'/> src='es'/>abstract'/>7.jp<'/>'/>'/> src='['/><'/>'/>'/> src='<'/>'/>'/> src='<'/>'/>'/> src=']`

for this image as an example:

```
http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your regular expressions, the brackets need escaping:

```
var message = message.replace(/\[img\]/g,"<img src='");
var message = message.replace(/\[\/img\]/g,"'/>");
```